# Can I change the Dojo namespace to something other than dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo, namespaces

I know you can do it for jQuery using jQuery.noConflict.  Is there a way to do something similar with Dojo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can. See [this page](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/multiversion.html) about running more than one version of Dojo on a page. It's fiddly, but seems to be what you're looking for.

In general, both Dojo and jQuery have been quite careful not to clobber each other's or anyone else's variable names.

Comment: The "this page" link above is no longer active, the content has been moved to here:

http://docs.dojocampus.org/multiversion/index